# Nginx try_files not working for urls ending in .php

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

The try_files directive in my Nginx configuration file seems to only work in particular situations. Here is what I'm working with:

```
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /route.php?_route_url=$uri;
    }
```

If I navigate to /admin/popups/image.php it correctly loads because that is an existing file - (I believe this is the first arg in the try_files statement hitting). If I go to /admin/webpages/ it correctly loads - this would be the third arg - /admin/webpages/ does not exist and route.php pulls in a file at /modules/webpages/admin/index.php. When I go to /admin/webpages/edit.php I get a 404. It seems to me that it should hit the third arg in the try_files and work. If I navigate to /route.php?_route_url=/admin/webpages/edit.php it works fine.

I've been banging my head on this for a bit and I can't figure it out. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't see it. Thanks.

UPDATE:
Upon further investigation it seems this block is not reflecting the change that should happen in the try_files above:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Not sure if that'll help. I'm guessing I need to make the original block take effect before this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one but make sure you adding this one between server { }

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /route.php?_route_url=$args;    
}
```

Don't forget to restart nginx service

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem by adding this rewrite line

`rewrite ^/admin/((?!popups).)*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.php?)$ /route.php?_route_url=$uri&$args last;`

Thankfully I only have one actual directory within /admin/.